# How to get the address of the freshly looked up hostname in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, events, dns

I am to write out the freshly looked up IP address of a hostname in Node.js:

```
var net = require('net');

var sock = net.Socket();

sock.on('lookup', function(e)
{
console.log('DNS lookup');
console.log(address);
} )
```

...

```
sock.connect(80, 'google.com');
```

https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_lookup

says that the `lookup` event is

> Emitted after resolving the hostname but before connecting. Not applicable to UNIX sockets.

```
err <Error> | <null> The error object. See dns.lookup().
address <string> The IP address.
family <string> | <null> The address type. See dns.lookup().
host <string> The hostname.
```

But which object has these fields? I tried them as simple variable names -- did not work, and as fields of the `e` object possibly passed to the anonymous function that I register for the `lookup` event -- that also did not work.

How can I access these fields upon lookup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get all the params in the callback, see the code below.

```
var net = require('net');

var sock = net.Socket();
const options = {
    host: "google.com",
    port: 80
};

sock.connect(options);

sock.on('lookup', function(err, address, family, host) {
    console.log(address);
    console.log(family);
    console.log(host);
    console.log(err);
});
```